# Error "not found or unable to stat" Centos

Tags: php, php7, servidor, centos

estoy teniendo un problema con mi servidor centos y recibo esto en mi log de errores del vesta.

```
[Sun Feb 02 15:53:12.420399 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23290] [client 170.239.84.63:41642] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Feb 02 15:56:40.630227 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23032] [client 170.239.84.63:52182] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Feb 02 15:58:24.567327 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23034] [client 170.239.84.63:43790] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://mes.backlab.at/wp-login.php
[Sun Feb 02 16:05:17.739574 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23731] [client 170.239.84.63:37048] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Feb 02 16:07:56.681984 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23032] [client 170.239.84.63:34700] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Feb 02 16:08:27.395062 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23731] [client 170.239.84.63:39110] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.jim-harvey.com/wp-login.php
[Sun Feb 02 16:08:28.223691 2020] [php7:error] [pid 23034] [client 170.239.84.63:39234] script '/home/admin/web/server.pe/public_html/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.jim-harvey.com/xmlrpc.php
```

¿Alguno sabe como que es o como puedo evitarlo?

Tengo en fail2ban y el iptables funcionando.

Comment: En las marcas de tiempo los errores ocurren cada dos minutos, lo cual hace pensar que se trata de un intento de ataque de fuerza bruta. Hay bots que lanzan intentos de acceso a tu Wordpress con mucha frecuencia. A pesar de tener `fail2ban` quizá convenga bloquear vía `.htaccess` los accesos a ciertos ficheros sensibles, como son siempre `wp-login.php` y `wp-admin.php`. Dado que es un proceso que parece fácil, pero no lo es, en mi caso uso un plugin que me permite cambiar mi URL de login a Wordpress por otra y los accesos a `wp-login.php` y `wp-admin.php` están bloqueados.

Comment: El problema es que yo no tengo wordpress instalado en esa ubicación ¿Que podría hacer?

Comment: Pero ¿estás en hosting compartido? Puede ser que haya más sitios en tu servidor y que los ataques estén llegando a esos sitios. Dependiendo de tu hosting, es fácil ver si hay más sitios que comparten tu mismo servidor y qué sitios son. Por ejemplo en Bluehost con ver los error_logs desde cPanel ya sabes qué otros sitios hay y que ataques están llegando a esos sitios.

Comment: Puedes pasarme el nombre de tu plugin por favor

Comment: ¿Qué plugin? ...

Comment: El plugin para cambiar la URL del login

Comment: Ah sí, se llama `All In One WP Security`. Es un plugin de seguridad con muchas configuraciones, entre ellas cambiar la URL de login por otra.